# Upgrade Oracle 10g to its higher version

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to upgrade Oracle 10.1.0 to its higher version 10.1.0.3
Is there any patch file to do this upgradation other than the fresh installation of the higher version?

Answer (score 3):

Patches are usually available on Oracle support site http://support.oracle.com. 
Currently available patches start from 10.2 version. 
More about versions, lifecycle support in
http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lifetime-support-technology-069183.pdf
(Your 10.1 version has limited support)

If you plan to change your environment, you can see that, in case of the problem, you would be on safer side if you choose to go to supported version (newer version) - you not only get help / workaround from support but also fixing patches if needed. 
But, of course, you know your environment and priorities better.

If you insist on 10.1 patch and have support contract, try to ask directly Oracle the patch you want. It is not sure you will get it, though.

Hope it helps